# В Telegram-боте после получения данных не добавляется кнопка `Новая`

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Написал Telegram-бота, который по нажатию на кнопку выводит данные из базы MySQL:

После получения данных не добавляется кнопка `Новая` на этапе `def send_echo(message)`. Если я правильно понимаю, то работает `bot handler`, но сам решения найти не могу.

```py
import telebot
from telebot import types


bot = telebot.TeleBot("xxxxxxxxxxxx")
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(user = 'pyth', password = '12345', host = '000.000.000.000', database = 'python', autocommit=True)
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM messages2")
result = mycursor.fetchall()
mydb.commit() 

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):

    name = message.from_user.first_name
    username = message.from_user.username
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    b1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('База данных 1', callback_data='first')
    markup.add(b1)
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет ' + name + ' нажми на кнопку что бы выгрузить БД', parse_mode='HTML', reply_markup=markup)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, step2)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def step2(call):

    if call.data == 'first':
        for x in result:
            ankets = [f'''Запись
От: {x[6]}
Id: {x[1]}
Login: {x[2]}
Город: {x[3]}
Температура: {x[4]}
В городе: {x[5]}''']
            msg = bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, ankets)
            bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, send_echo)

def send_echo(message):
            markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
            b3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Новая', callback_data='second')
            markup.add(b3)
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Привет', parse_mode='HTML', reply_markup=markup)

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: в каком месте тут читаются данные из базы?

Comment: @Эникейщик 
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(user = 'pyth', password = '12345', host = '000.000.000.000', database = 'python', autocommit=True) mycursor = mydb.cursor() mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM messages2") В верху данные для подключения к базе

Comment: ну так они читаются один раз при старте скрипта. Нажатие на кнопку не читает их заново.

Comment: @Эникейщик В идеале после выполнения скрипта, должна появиться кнопка, по которой можно было перечитать данные. Кнопку я добавил, но она тоже не появляется. Если знаешь, как поправить что бы появилась кнопка и перечитать по нажатию на нее, подскажи

Comment: этот код не будет перечитывать данные, хоть ты десять кнопок добавь. Код для чтения данных у тебя находится в начале скрипта и выполняется один раз. Чтобы нажатие на кнопку читало данные, код для чтения данных должен быть в обработчике нажатия.

Comment: @Эникейщик Да, спасибо! Данные вставил в обработчик, все обновляется, Отлично!!!! Может подскажешь, как сделать что бы после выполнения появлялась кнопка?

Comment: Все вопросы решены! Спасибо!